# Magento Base URL Redirecting To Old URL

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I seem to be hitting a brick wall here, I have just migrated my magento installation from my local environment to my test server here.

http://development.missbella.co.uk

However it keeps redirecitng to the old url at localhost.

I have updated the core_config_data table with the new address.
cleared the var cache folder multiple times
reindexed multiple times
cleared the cache multiple times
I even set the permissions on the var and cache folder to 777

None of this has seemed to have any affect and its driving me a bit crazy.

However I have found if I put the domain name and then a sub page that does work i.e.

http://development.missbella.co.uk/dresses.html

Does anyone have any idea what the problem may be?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your local.xml? 
if you have local.xml so please rename and hit the URL(your localhost or new installation url) after that undo the changes.

I had faced same issue and fixed by doing above steps. Hope it will work for you.

Also clear the browser cache too. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check two things:
Go to your local.xml file located in root/app/etc folder and check which db it points to. It will be like :

```
<dbname><![CDATA[magento]]></dbname>
```

Now you can go to the database and run the following query:

```
select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
```

and

```
select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Now check if this is your current URL if yes then I don't think there is an issue with your database, just clear your cache and you are good to go.

You can do the following from the backend as well:

Go to **System->Configuaration->General->Web->Unsecure/Secure** and check if it points to your current URL or not if it doesn't change it, clear the cache, and cookies of your browser and you are good to go.